# How to show interstitial Ads at the opening of the fragment?

Tags: android, interstitial

I am trying to show test interstitial Ads before the opening or loading of the fragment. My fragment is called from within other fragment and I put the code of test Ad inside onCreateView() of the fragment that I want to place ads before its opening but actually no Ad appear before showing (opening) that fragment while the same code is working and showing Ad when its placed inside onResume() of the same fragment class. Target API 16-30. Any help would be very appreciated.

Code snippet:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

View viewCalc2d=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calc2d, container, false);

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getActivity().getBaseContext());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    mInterstitialAd.show();
```

// Do something

}

Comment: bro its need to load your ad first then you can show the add when fragment start

Comment: In my case, what is the right place to load ads and what is right place to show ads?  Did you mean I have to load ad in the MainAactivity's onCreate() and just show it in the fragment's onCreatView?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1):

1.First make an object class as this

```
object AdmobUtil {

    private lateinit var interstitialAd: InterstitialAd

    fun loadAdmobInterstitialAd(context: Context) {

        interstitialAd = InterstitialAd(context)

        interstitialAd.adUnitId = interstitialAdUnitId

        interstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())

    }

    fun showInterstitialAd() {
        if (interstitialAd.isLoaded) interstitialAd.show()
    }

}
```

2.Load add before showing fragment

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_main) {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       AdmobUtil.loadAdmobInterstitialAd(this)
    }
}
```

3. now show loaded ad

```
class AdFragment: Fragment(R.layout.fragment_ad) {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        AdmobUtil.showInterstitialAd()
    }
}
```

Java Version

```
public static class AdmobUtil {

    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd = null;

    public void loadAdmobInterstitialAd(Context ontext) {

        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);

        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(interstitialAdUnitId);

        interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    }

    public void showInterstitialAd() {
        if (interstitialAd.isLoaded) interstitialAd.show();
    }

}
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity() {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AdmobUtil.loadAdmobInterstitialAd(this);
    }
}
```

```
public class AdFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ad, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        AdmobUtil.showInterstitialAd();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you bro. Although its Kotlin code, but the concept was helpful.

Comment: well is my answer helps solve your problem then please accept it as the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Finally its done..

1: Created a public class to hold my InterstitialAd Ad object :

public class globals {

```
public static InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
```

}

2: Initialized and Loaded add inside MainActivity's onCreate():

```
globals.mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    globals.mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    globals.mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

3: Showing Ad inside target fragment's onCreateView() :

```
if (!globals.mInterstitialAd.isLoaded())
        globals.mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    globals.mInterstitialAd.show();
```